# Popup needs to refer back to textbox within a content control

Tags: javascript, asp.net, calendar, popup, master-pages

I have a link that is located inside a content control. This link calls a javascript function that opens a popup window containing a calendar and passes it the transformed id from the server of a textbox control using clientid. I need to be able to click on a date and have the popup close and insert the date into the textbox of the id I passed into the function which again, is located inside the content control.

This is the link in the content control:

```
<a title="Pick Date from Calendar" onclick="calendarPicker('form1.<%= txtstart.ClientId %>');" href="javascript:void(0);">
```

This is the javascript inside the masterpage:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function calendarPicker(strField) {
    var strField = window.open('DatePicker.aspx?field=' + strField, 'calendarPopup', 'width=250,height=190,resizable=yes');
}
```

The calendar is a calendar control inside its own page and this is the codebehind:

```
Private Sub Calendar1_DayRender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DayRenderEventArgs) Handles Calendar1.DayRender
        Dim link As New System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl
Dim strLink As String
e.Cell.Controls.Clear()
link.TagName = "a"
link.InnerText = e.Day.DayNumberText
strLink = "JavaScript:window.opener.document." & Request.QueryString("Field") & ".value = '" & e.Day.Date & "'; window.close();"
link.Attributes.Add("href", strLink)
If (e.Day.IsSelected) Then
  link.Attributes.Add("style", Calendar1.SelectedDayStyle.ToString())
End If
e.Cell.Controls.Add(link)
End Sub
```

I should also mention the error I'm getting is:

window.opener.document.form1 is undefined

Comment: I'm getting a javascript error and it's not referring back to the original window and setting the value of the textbox to the value of the date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't use `document.form1`. use `document.getElementById(strField)`. you'll also have to fix  your call to `calendarPicker`. `calendarPicker('<%= txtstart.ClientId %>');`

don't put javascript in the `href` property. use `link.Attributes.Add("onclick", strLink)`

Comment: Well if I weren't using a masterpage, everything works how I have it. I'll make the changes you suggest and see what works.

Comment: i'm making educated guesses since we don't know what your actual page looks like. post some html output if these suggestions don't help.